# Describing relations between interfaces

Tags: c#, .net, interface, multiple-inheritance

Consider this interface in FCL:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

It tells us: the interface `IList<T>` [XXX] the 3 interfaces: `IConnection<T>`,`IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`. I have some choices for [XXX]:

(1) derives from/inherits

This option comes from C# language specification(but not directly), where the word "multiple-inheritance interfaces" appears some times. The reason I don't like it: Using the word "inherit", we have: `IEnumerable<T>` inherits `IEnumerable`, `ICollection<T>` inherits both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable`, then `IList<T>` inherits all the three. Something is wrong but I can't tell, very bad feelings.

(2) implements

It's not a good option either. Because there is no implementation, it's a contract only.

(3) something else? I'd like to know

What's your idea?

Comment: Em..a vote for closing... maybe I should ask this question on english.stackexchange.com?

Comment: +1 Upvoting to prevent closing. IMO this is a valid programming question about terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say `IList<T>` ***includes*** `ICollection<T>`, `IEnumerable<T>`, and `IEnumerable`

Alternatively, I might say it ***extends***

Answer (score 3):

I used "Extends" for this. Might be a little Java-ish but it seems appropriate to me. An interface that has a super-interface can be reasonably said to "extend" that interface because it must add something to it (not necessarily or course, but there aren't many reasons not to. Except maybe semantic reasons, but then you're still *extending* semantically).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say an *interface* is implemented and a class is *inherited*. Is that what you're asking?

If yes, here's why:

- An interface describes a contract which objects who use that contract must **implement**. If an interface is based on another interface, I'd say it "extends" or "is derived from" that interface. If it is a class, then it implements the interface.
- A class exposes functionality for other objects to **inherit** and extend.

The reason I don't use "inherits" do describe both situations is because you don't inherit anything from an interface, e.g. there is no functional substance to an interface - just a blueprint of what the concrete object will do.

Comment: So you choose option (2)? That is, `IList<T>` implements `IEnumerable`? But where is the implementation?